# How To Cancel Any Current Parallel.ForEach And Start Fresh

Tags: .net, parallel.foreach

Functionally have a long list of words bound to a ListView.  Use a TextBox for  chars to filter the list of words.

With any new char need to cancel any processing background filter.  Then wait 1 second (DispatcherTimer) to start a fresh background parallel filter.

Have this working using BackGroundWorker but cannot translate the cancel-any-processing part to Parallel.
Basically need "if (backgroundWorkerFTSfilter.IsBusy) backgroundWorkerFTSfilter.CancelAsync();" in Parallel.
If I am going about this wrong please let me know.

```
private List<FTSword> fTSwordsFiltered = new List<FTSword>();
CancellationTokenSource ftsCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
ParallelOptions ftspo = new ParallelOptions();
// in ctor ftspo.CancellationToken = ftsCts.Token;

public List<FTSword> FTSwordsFiltered  // ListView bound to
{
    get { return fTSwordsFiltered; }
    set
    {
        if (fTSwordsFiltered == value) return;
        fTSwordsFiltered = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("FTSwordsFiltered");
    }
}
public string FTSwordFilter            // TextBox bound to
{
    get { return fTSwordFilter; }
    set
    {
        if (value == fTSwordFilter) return;

        fTSwordFilter = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("FTSwordFilter");

        // cancel any filter currently processing
        ftsCts.Cancel();   // fts filter              
        // with BackgroundWorker this was able to cancel               
        // if (backgroundWorkerFTSfilter.IsBusy) backgroundWorkerFTSfilter.CancelAsync();

        dispatcherTimerFTSfilter.Stop();
        // wait 1 second and apply filter in background
        dispatcherTimerFTSfilter.Start();
    }
}
private void dispatcherTimerFTSfilter_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dispatcherTimerFTSfilter.Stop();
    List<FTSword> ftsWords = new List<FTSword>();
    //ftsCts = new CancellationTokenSource();  with these two it never cancels
    //ftspo.CancellationToken = ftsCts.Token;
    if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(FTSwordFilter)))
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {

            try
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(FTSwords, ftspo, ftsw =>
                {
                    if (ftsw.WordStem.StartsWith(FTSwordFilter))
                    {
                        ftsWords.Add(ftsw);
                    }
                    ftspo.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                });
                Thread.Sleep(1000);   // so the next key stoke has time
                FTSwordsFiltered = (List<FTSword>)ftsWords;
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ei)
            {
                // problem is that it is always cancelled from the cancel request before DispatchTimer
                Debug.WriteLine(ei.Message);
            }
            Debug.WriteLine(ftsWords.Count.ToString() + "parallel ");
        });           
    }
}
```

The answer from Irman led me to this

```
    if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(FTSwordFilter)))
    {
        string startWorkFilter = FTSwordFilter;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                fTSwordsFilteredCancel = false;
                Parallel.ForEach(FTSwords, ftspo, (ftsw, loopstate) =>
                {
                    if (ftsw.WordStem.StartsWith(startWorkFilter))
                    {
                        ftsWords.Add(ftsw);
                    }
                    // Thread.Sleep(1);
                    if (fTSwordsFilteredCancel)
                    {
                        loopstate.Break();
                    }
                });
                Debug.WriteLine("fTSwordsFilteredCancel " + fTSwordsFilteredCancel.ToString());
                FTSwordsFiltered = (List<FTSword>)ftsWords;
                Debug.WriteLine(ftsWords.Count.ToString() + " parallel " + startWorkFilter);                       
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ei)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ei.Message);
            }
        });
    }
```

Very grateful for the answer I and will use this for some longer running tasks or longer list but got such great performance I moved this to the get (still with a 1 second delay).    Results in a smaller memory footprint.   Against 800,000 it runs in less than 1/10 second.

```
public IEnumerable<FTSword> FTSwordsFiltered
{
    get 
    { 
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(FTSwordFilter) || FTSwordFilter == "*") return FTSwords; 
        return FTSwords.AsParallel().Where(ftsWrd => ftsWrd.WordStem.StartsWith(FTSwordFilter));
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parallel.ForEach comes with ParallelLoopState object. you can use this object to break the loop.

you can either use `loopState.Break()` or `loopState.Stop()` based on your requirements.

check this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991486.aspx

Comment: Please check what I think is the correct use of loopState.Break() before I mark as answered.  (the parallel version was so fast I had to put a sleep in the Parallel.ForEach to even have time to cancel)

Comment: It looks good. If you don't want to use Cancellation Token, you can remove parallel option object passed in Parallel.ForEach call. BTW - ParallelOption is also used to limit the number of Processors used to run this call.

Comment: In the ctor I set the ftspo.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Environment.ProcessorCount; to keep things constrained.